# Database Design SQL

Tags: database, t-sql, database-design

My question is: Notice that I am putting MvrId in many tables. What is your opinion of the following desing below. How can I improve it? If you point me to a book I hope is to a page of a book.[image] 
You can just execute this script on a database called MedicalVariance if you want to see the whole thing.

```
 USE MedicalVariance; 
    --This is a quick install script 
    --I guess you could even execute this from the front end but that would be overkill 
    --Because of the audience that will install this software are DBA's 

IF EXISTS
(
--The query below will will evaluate to true if it finds a foreign key constraint.
    SELECT 1 From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE LIKE 'FOREIGN KEY'
)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @TableName      NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @ConstraintName NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @DynamicSQLEXEC NVARCHAR(300)
    --DECLARE AND FEED THE CURSOR DATA
    Declare ConstraintCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    -- Dont worry I wont drop your precious FOREIGN KEYS since the catalog must be MedicalVariance
    SELECT TABLE_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE LIKE 'FOREIGN KEY'
          AND 
          CONSTRAINT_CATALOG LIKE 'MedicalVariance'

    --OPEN THE CURSOR 
    OPEN ConstraintCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM ConstraintCursor
    INTO @TableName, @ConstraintName

    --NOW IMPLEMENT THE LOGIC TO DROP ALL CONSTRAINTS
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    BEGIN

        --DYNAMIC SQL IS A PAIN IF YOU THINK YOU GOT BETTER SYNTAX GO FOR IT
        SET @DynamicSQLEXEC ='ALTER TABLE '-- the space is important
        SET @DynamicSQLEXEC =@DynamicSQLEXEC + @TableName + ' '
        SET @DynamicSQLEXEC =@DynamicSQLEXEC + 'DROP CONSTRAINT '
        SET @DynamicSQLEXEC =@DynamicSQLEXEC + @ConstraintName
        PRINT @DynamicSQLEXEC -- make sure this is correct sql syntax
        EXEC(@DynamicSQLEXEC)
        -----------------------Dynamic SQL ENDS-------------------------------------
        FETCH NEXT FROM ConstraintCursor
        INTO @TableName, @ConstraintName
    END;
    CLOSE ConstraintCursor
    DEALLOCATE ConstraintCursor

END;
GO


IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrMeds'
    )
            BEGIN

                DROP TABLE MvrMeds
            END;
            GO
IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'Mvr'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.Mvr
            END;
            GO
IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrMedsAdminRoute'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrMedsAdminRoute
            END;
            GO
IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrMedsPrescribingErrors'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrMedsPrescribingErrors
            END;
            GO
IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrMedsTranscribingErrors'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrMedsTranscribingErrors
            END;
            GO
IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrMedsProductIssuesErrors'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrMedsProductIssuesErrors
            END;
            GO  
IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrMedsProcumentErrors'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrMedsProcumentErrors
            END;
            GO  
IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrMedsDispensingErrors'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrMedsDispensingErrors
            END;
            GO  
IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrMedsAdministrationErrors'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrMedsAdministrationErrors
            END;
            GO  

    IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrMedsDocumentationErrors'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrMedsDocumentationErrors
            END;
            GO  

    IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrEmployees'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrEmployees
            END;
            GO          

    IF EXISTS
    (
            SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables
            WHERE  Table_Name = 'MvrCommunicationErrors'
    )
            BEGIN 
                DROP TABLE dbo.MvrCommunicationErrors
            END;
            GO  
-- The way I am putting MvrId in almost every table 
-- Do you recommend it or bless it as good desing?


 CREATE TABLE Mvr
 (
    MvrId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
 )
  CREATE TABLE MvrMedsAdminRoute
 (
    MvrMedsAdminRouteId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrId INT
 )
 CREATE TABLE MvrMeds
 ( 
    MvrMedsId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrId INT ,
    MvrMedsAdminRouteId  INT ,
    CONSTRAINT MvrMeds_Mvr_FK FOREIGN KEY(MvrId) REFERENCES dbo.Mvr(MvrID),
    CONSTRAINT MvrMeds_MvrMedsAdminRoute_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrMedsAdminRouteId) REFERENCES dbo.MvrMedsAdminRoute(MvrMedsAdminRouteId)
 )

 CREATE TABLE MvrMedsPrescribingErrors
 (
    MvrPrescribingErrorId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrMedsId        INT ,
    MvrId INT
    CONSTRAINT MvrMedsPrescribingErrors_MvrMeds_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrMedsId) REFERENCES dbo.MvrMeds(MvrMedsId)
 )

 CREATE TABLE MvrMedsTranscribingErrors
 (
    MvrTranscribingErrorsId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrMedsId INT ,
    MvrId INT
    CONSTRAINT MvrMedsTranscribingErrors_MvrMeds_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrMedsId) REFERENCES dbo.MvrMeds(MvrMedsId)
 )
 CREATE TABLE MvrMedsProductIssuesErrors
 (
    MvrTranscribingErrorsId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrMedsId INT ,
    MvrId INT
    CONSTRAINT MvrMedsProductIssuesErrors_MvrMeds_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrMedsId) REFERENCES dbo.MvrMeds(MvrMedsId)
 )

 CREATE TABLE MvrMedsProcumentErrors 
 (
    MvrProcumentErrorsId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrMedsId INT,
    MvrId INT
    CONSTRAINT MvrMedsOrderingProcumentErrors_MvrMeds_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrMedsId) REFERENCES dbo.MvrMeds(MvrMedsId)
 )
 CREATE TABLE MvrMedsDispensingErrors
 (
    MvrDispensingErrorsId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrMedsId INT,
    MvrId INT
    CONSTRAINT MvrMedsDispensingErrors_MvrMeds_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrMedsId) REFERENCES dbo.MvrMeds(MvrMedsId)
 )

 CREATE TABLE MvrMedsAdministrationErrors 
 (
    MvrAdministrationErrorsId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrMedsId INT,
    MvrId INT
    CONSTRAINT MvrMedsAdministrationErrors_MvrMeds_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrMedsId) REFERENCES dbo.MvrMeds(MvrMedsId)
 )

 CREATE TABLE MvrMedsDocumentationErrors
 (
    MvrDocumentationErrorsId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrMedsId INT, 
    MvrId INT
    CONSTRAINT MvrMedsDocumentationErrors_MvrMeds_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrMedsId) REFERENCES dbo.MvrMeds(MvrMedsId)
 )


----EMPLOYEES 
--ONLY EMPLOYEES CAN BE PART OF MVR?
CREATE TABLE MvrEmployees 
(
    MvrEmployeesId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrId INT, 
    CONSTRAINT MvrEmployees_Mvr_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrId) REFERENCES dbo.Mvr(MvrId)
)

CREATE TABLE  MvrCommunicationErrors
(
    MvrCommunicationErrorsId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MvrEmployeesId INT, 
    MvrId INT,
    CONSTRAINT MvrCommunicationErrors_MvrEmployees_FK FOREIGN KEY (MvrEmployeesId) REFERENCES dbo.MvrEmployees(MvrEmployeesId)
)
```

Comment: If you're asking a question, please don't just dump a huge amount of code and ask people what they think of it. Ask specific questions that others will understand.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a specific field in every table if every table is related to a core object.  Beyond that I don't know what to say...

Comment: Thank you, I think I asked a specific question. The question was what do you think of putting a specific field on every table like mellamokb said. The code is just for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `MvrId` in all tables come from the primary key `MvrId` in table `Mvr` you should have a foreign key constraint on all `MvrId` columns. At least if you want to have control over what `MvrId`'s is used in the other tables.

You have not specified why you added `MvrId` to all those table and depending on how you want the values to be used it can be necessary or it can be a bad idea.

It is necessary if it adds some information about the entity where it is stored it is unnecessary if that information could be retrieved using a relationship to another table.

Ex: `MvrMedsPrescribingErrors` is a child table to `MvrMeds` with FK `MvrMedsId`. If you can use `MvrMedsId` in `MvrMedsPrescribingErrors` to find the associated `MvrId` in `MvrMeds` then I would not not store `MvrId` in `MvrMedsPrescribingErrors`.

But if on the other hand you can store `MvrId`'s in `MvrMedsPrescribingErrors` that is not the same as the `MvrId` on the related `MvrMeds` row then it is absolutely necessary to have `MvrId` in `MvrMedsPrescribingErrors`

Comment: The thing is that MvrId that the form is created in stages of review. Someone fill out the form and it produces a MvrId. Then a month later someone reviews that MvrId and puts more data in the record. So if I put a constraint it will force me to insert records at the same time right?

Comment: @jvelez - no you just have to make sure that you add a row to Mvr first.

Comment: Ok thank you. Your comments helped me developed a better design.